# proof if sequince $x_n$ tends to zero then sequence $\frac{1}{x_n}$ converges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits

i'am try to prove a little theorem about limit of sequence:

**Theorem 1:**
if $\lim_{n \to\ \infty}{x_n} = 0$ and $x_n \neq 0 $ for all n,  then $lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{x_n} } = \infty $

**My proof:**

Since we have $$\lim_{n \to\ \infty}{x_n} = 0$$
so by defenition exist $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $n \geqslant N$  we have $|x_n| < e$ where $e>0$

put $e = \frac{1}{k}$ where $k > 0$ then we have 
$$|x_n| < e=\frac{1}{k}$$  and, therefore **(???)**,
$$|\frac{1}{x_n}| > k$$
by the defenition of limit of sequence converges to infinity (since E arbitrary just put E = k) we have 
$$lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{x_n} } = \infty $$
and we are done!

any advice? it is a right proof?

**UPD: rewrite theorem**

Comment: Counterexample: $x_n = -1/n$.

Comment: **You have to assume $x_n>0$ !** If you don't know the sign of $x_n$ like with sequence $1/(-1)^n$, the theorem, as written, is false.

Comment: You're assuming $x_n$ is increasing. In this case you're right, but if $x_n$ is decreasing, then you get $-\infty$ in the limit.

Comment: Don't "open" the absolute value and you are correct.

Comment: I need a transition from absolute to unequal without it.

Comment: also "converges to $\infty$" is abusive, the sequence still diverges.

Answer (score 1):

**No the statement isn't right** 
And what you've just proved implies that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1}{|x_n|} = \infty$$
Because generally $ \frac {1}{|x_n|} \gt k \implies \frac {1}{x_n} \gt k$ or $ \frac {1}{x_n} \lt -k $

So you can't say for sure if $x_n \ne 0$ then whether $\frac{1}{x_n} \to \infty$ solely or $\frac{1}{x_n} \to - \infty$ solely. If $x_n$ has positive and negative values then this will happen and the sequence will oscillate between $- \infty$ to $\infty$.

In order to have $\frac{1}{x_n} \to \infty$  or $\frac{1}{x_n} \to - \infty$ you need to have $x_n \gt 0$ and $x_n \lt 0$ respectively for all $n\ge N_0, N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

No, **the theorem is not correct**, nor is the proof.

It suffices to show one counterexample.

Let $x_n=(-1)^n\frac 1 n$. It can be shown that $\lim _{n\to+\infty} x_n=0$, but sequence $\frac 1 {x_n}$ won't diverge to $+\infty$; it will oscillate.

Comment: Sorry, rewrite theorem

Comment: @KarlosMargaritos sorry but I can't see why the theorem is correct after edit. One need the condition $x_i \gt 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Doesn't that follow from the conditions of the theorem? If 1/x_n > k > 0 then x_n > 0

Comment: @KarlosMargaritos on my computer the theorem appears to be "**Theorem 1:** if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$ and $x_n\not =0$ for all n, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {x_n} = \infty$"... However I can see the bold "UPD: rewrite theorem". It is strange, maybe check if you really *successfully* updated your theorem...

Comment: What will be the correct interpretation of the theorem suitable for both negative and positive x_n values?

Comment: @KarlosMargaritos the theorem does not state whether $x_n$ is positive or negative, it just said that $x_n \not=0$... So one can select whatever non-zero value one likes as long as $x_n$ approaches zero

Comment: maybe I was wrong about the formulas.